# SendGrid SMTP API dll taking a long time to load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, sendgrid

I have an ASP.NET MVC app built with VS 2013.

I have included the SendGrid C# library via NUGET. All installed and works perfectly. The following versions are reported by Package Manager:

> SendGrid 5.1.0
>
> SendGrid.SmtpApi 1.2.1

My problem is that whenever I start the application locally, it's taking a long time to load the SendGrid SMPT API. In VS I see the following in the status bar along the bottom:

`Loading symbols for SendGrid.SmtpApi.dll`

It then hangs there for up to about 30 seconds until it finally finishes and the browser finishes loading.

Admittedly not a huge problem on it's own but becomes a pain when doing that operation many times per day.

Is anyone else getting this? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: Hello, mind opening an issue on github for this? https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-csharp/ It's probably a bad path to the symbol file. Thanks!

Comment: @bwest Done: https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-csharp/issues/15

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by doing this:

Explicitly adding SendGrid.SmtpApi.dll and SendGrid.dll to the Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols->Excluded Symbols sped up my application startup time by 30 seconds.

Thanks to janvanderhaegen in https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-csharp/issues/15